# When I add the chip-group, The program does not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-chips

I got a problem in the Chip-Group section.
This is the first time I use the Chip and Chip-Group, so I must download it.
When I clicked the download button. They ask me: "This operation requires the library `com.google.android.material:material:+`,  Would you like to add this now? "
If I press the Yes button, Material is added correctly but with an error.

when I clicked the run button I got an error.

## the error message is :

### [image]

```
apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/gradle.properties"
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion "${versions.buildTools}"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.twilio.video.quickstart"
    minSdkVersion versions.minSdk
    targetSdkVersion versions.targetSdk
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    buildConfigField("String",
            "TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN",
            "\"${getSecretProperty("TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN", "TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN")}\"")
    buildConfigField("String",
            "TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN_SERVER",
            "\"${getSecretProperty("TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN_SERVER", "https://secure.advcare.info/mobapp/v1.0/adv/")}\"")
    buildConfigField("boolean",
            "USE_TOKEN_SERVER",
            "${getSecretProperty("USE_TOKEN_SERVER", false)}")
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility versions.java
    targetCompatibility versions.java
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

// Specify that we want to split up the APK based on ABI
splits {
    abi {
        // Enable ABI split
        enable true

        // Clear list of ABIs
        reset()

        // Specify each architecture currently supported by the Video SDK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"

        // Specify that we do not want an additional universal SDK
        universalApk false
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation "com.twilio:video-android:${versions.videoAndroid}"
    implementation "com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:${versions.ion}"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.supportLibrary}"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:${versions.supportLibrary}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${versions.supportLibrary}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0"
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ceryle:SegmentedButton:v2.0.2'
    //This is added after press yes.
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'


}
```

If I remove the material from the code

> ('com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0')

My program works correctly.

help me

Comment: You are using androidx and support libraries together and you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First migrate your project to `androidX` going to `refactor -> Migrate to androidX`.
- Add dependency implementation `'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`'
  or
  `implementation` '`com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08`'

Then use Chip-Group as:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
     android:id="@+id/reflow_group"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/txt_this" />
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

[Explore more](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

Answer (score 0):

> Duplicate class (...) found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core....) and classes.jar (com.android.support....)

Try [migrating your code to androidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), that should fix the problem.

Comment: I think that's right but it does not work for me. When i put "android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true" in Gradle.properties file they said:
ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':quickstart' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: > ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':quickstart' of type org.gradle.api.Project

have you added "apply plugin: 'com.android.library' " to your build.gradle?

Answer (score -1):

I think that's right but it does not work for me. When i put  **"android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true"** in **Gradle.properties file** I got the error:

## ERROR:

Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':quickstart' of type org.gradle.api.Project.